# Can't seem to get error handling in PowerShell script when calling cmd /c batch file

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that runs 4 commands for each dataset found. I am trying to add error handling, so if I get a error on the first CMD result, not to process the other 3 for that user set.

I tried the below as well as adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to the CMD commands. However, it's not working.

Any ideas how I can catch the exception?

```bsh
foreach ($row in $Dataset.tables[0].rows) {
    try {
        cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\script.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -devmwp $UserID;$DeviceID;1;1439 2>&1 >> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
        cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\script.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -usrspvs $UserID;${App}:$Track >> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
        cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\script.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -appi $UserID;$DeviceID;$App >> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
        cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\script.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -usrcpvs $UserID>> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
    } catch {
        Write ("Catch Failure")
        break
    }
}
```

Exception is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "userId",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "No user was found for the given id.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "No user was found for the given id."
}
    at
```

Solution from @Lee_Dailey:

```bsh
foreach ($row in $Dataset.tables[0].rows) {
    cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\playinvoker.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -devmwp $GoogleUserID;$GoogleDeviceID;1;1439 2>&1 >> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
    if (!$LastExitCode) {
        cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\playinvoker.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -usrspvs $GoogleUserID;${App}:$Track >> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
        cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\playinvoker.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -appi $GoogleUserID;$GoogleDeviceID;$App >> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
        cmd.exe /c "$PSScriptRoot\bin\playinvoker.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -usrcpvs $GoogleUserID >> $PSScriptRoot\${FileName}_REST_${DateTime}.txt";
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just run your file from powershell instead of using PS to call a batch file?

Comment: from what i can tell, the ONLY thing you will get back from a CMD call is an error code OR the text of the output. calls to CMD do NOT trigger powershell errors. you must parse the returned info to see if you have an error. you likely want to look into `$LastExitCode`.

Comment: When i run the command in power shell i fails on the semicolons needed for the parameters. PS seems to terminate on the first ; and i cant find a way to escape them

.\script.bat -c $PSScriptRoot\bin\config.groovy -devmwp userId;deviceid;1;1439

Comment: adding solution in main post that @Lee_Dailey advised. Thanks, this seems to work

Comment: @rcmpayne - kool! glad to know you got it working ... [*grin*]

Comment: Right on, props to @Lee_Dailey